# Landing Page preview REST API in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, automationstudio, landing-page

We have a static landing page (no forms to submit) with some dynamic content like disclosures. The static content doesn't change much, but the disclosures do and the disclosure have all the legal jargon, so we want to backup how the page was rendered each day into an archival.

I have two questions:

- Just like API for email preview, is there any **API to get Landing Page html.**
- In addition to getting the Landing Page html for that particular user, I want to take a **backup of how the Landing Page is rendered each day**.(with no action from the end user)

I am checking to see, if there is some API that I can invoke to get the preview, save the HTML in a DE and run the automation each day. **Web scraping is not an option**

Greatly appreciate, if anyone came across a similar issue and have any inputs.

Thank you
Raj

Answer (score 1):

There are no Cloud Page API endpoints. You can interact to a degree via the Content Builder Asset REST API, but not beyond just the content part (raw with AMPscript/SSJS - not rendered). There are 'internal' endpoints that are used in the UI, but we, as end users, do not have token authorization to use these endpoints.

What you can do instead is do an HTTP GET to the page passing in the specific parameters you want for each person (if you are using the CloudPagesURL to pass parameters, it might be trickier though) and it will return the HTML of that page. The issue you run into here is that this will cost you a Super message for each GET you run as it will count as a page view. So this can get expensive quick.

This is one of the huge gaps in API accessibility that SFMC has and is definitely something I advocate for improvement.